# Pyspark Dataframe groupby few columns and transpose all other columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have about 350 columns in a pyspark datafarme and I would want to groupby few columns in the dataframe and transpose all other columns to rows

```
array = ['id',
 'date','name']
cols=df.columns
main_list = list(set(cols) - set(array))
len(main_list)

def stack_multiple_col(df,c=main_list,output_columns=["metrics","metric_values"]):

  return (f"""stack({len(c)},{','.join(map(','.join,
         (zip([f'"{i}"' for i in c],c))))}) as ({','.join(output_columns)})""")


df.select(cols).selectExpr(stack_multiple_col(main_list)).show()
```

I would want df to groupby columns in array list and then transpose all other columns in main_list to rows. The above expression has been throwing me an error. Is there an easier way of doin it?

It converts all columns to rows, but I want only selected columns to convert to rows.

Comment: And where is the error?

Comment: @blackbishop It converts all columns to rows, but I want only selected columns to convert to rows.